# Group Policy WMI Filter query

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, wmi, groups

I'm putting in place a policy to install AV software but only want it to apply when the computer has no AV software installed, I know WMI can be used for this but don't have a clue how it can be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to tackle this problem... The Win32_Prodct WMI class is probably the worst and slowest way.

Consider using Group Policy Preferences as an alternative. Specifically, using Item-level targeting to determine whether the software is installed or not.

[image: Item-level targeting]

There are also registry and file system options in Item-level targeting so you can work with the product even if it is not an MSI-based installer.

For further reading, see http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2012/04/19/how-to-not-use-win32-product-in-group-policy-filtering.aspx#pi159210=1